# what it means for my page if it needs ready() to work

Tags: jquery, dom, callback, firebug, domready

When I run from firebug console the code below it works without any problem

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
   jQuery('h2').click( function()   {
      jQuery(this).next().next().hide();
   });
});
```

But when I remove the `jQuery(document).ready`, my code doesn't work.

```
jQuery('h2').click( function() {
   jQuery(this).next().next().hide();
});
```

[ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) means that document ( images etc ) is loaded in my browser *then* fire the event. But if the first block of code works ( means that the DOM is ready ) shouldn't the seconf block of code run too ?

I guess I'm missing something, but what I understand is that in both cases, the code should run, because the document is loaded in my browser.

Or maybe there is an error in the page code that hinders the code execution.

PS: the code page is just a wordpress page in my localhost.

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/ready/](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @Dom if you read my question you will see that I refer to the link you posted

Comment: You are writing it in the console, *after* the page has been loaded (which presumably will last a fraction of a second), so the document is already *ready*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the point of `ready`.

`ready` will be called once it's called, not when the DOM is read, the callback `ready` receives will fire when the DOM is read.

```
// The DOM isn't read yet, though you can call the `.ready` function.
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    // Here, inside the callback, the DOM is ready.
    jQuery('h2').click( function()  {
        jQuery(this).next().next().hide();
    });
});
```

Let's say to load the DOM takes two seconds, a simplified illustration of the timeline:

```
// Timeline- 00:00
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    // Timeline- 00:02
    jQuery('h2').click( function()  {
        // Timeline- When ever you clicked on the <h2>
        jQuery(this).next().next().hide();
    });
});
```

Just like with your click callback:

```
jQuery('h2').click( function()  {
```

It doesn't say the `<h2>` was clicked, but it registers a callback to fire when it will be clicked.

---

One small but important note:

> ready() means that document ( **images** etc ) is loaded in my browser then fire the event.

No, that what javascript native `onload` function means, `ready` means that the **DOM** is ready, meaning the HTML structure(including images) was loaded on the client browser and ready to be manipulated, it doesn't mean the **images** (or iframe) were loaded(the actual image), that is what `onload` for.

Comment: @mt0s, You can call it that way.

Comment: yeah I see now I get it. Great answer, great examples thank you very much. It took me a lot of time reading the api and making examples and didn't understand nothing until now

Comment: Your note is exactly the reason why I didn't understand. 
A loaded DOM **isn't** a ready ( to manipulate with jQuery ) DOM.

Comment: @mt0s, Sorry, I didn't understand the last comment.

Comment: about the DOM? I say that when the document loads doesn't means its ready to manipulate it with jQuery and that's the reason why we need the `.ready` . If you mean your note I mean the last paragraph you added made the things more clear for me.

Comment: @mt0s, ohh o.k. I'm glad you understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the second one doesn't work is because by the time your script runs to register the click event it wont find the element $('h2') in the DOM as it has not been loaded already. Thats why you need to use $.ready(readyhandler) or $(function(){readyhandlerCode}); so with this the events will be registered once your document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

jquery(document).ready() is
A function to execute after the DOM is ready.

While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received.
The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

So all the DOM handler codes like

```
jQuery('h2').click( function()  {
        jQuery(this).next().next().hide();
    });
```

will be guaranteed to be called only within

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
...

}
```

Block or from any other function. After the dom document is ready, the handlers are also ready to be run.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question.